# How to loop a nested loop in bash without repetition?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write two loops that would make a function together as I require both variables in one deployment for azure such as a name of storage account and container name to contain their key and store it but I am getting repeated results.

```sh
    for storage in $(cat $TMP_FILE_STORAGE | sed 's/^[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' )
    do
      echo $storage
      for container in $(cat $TMP_FILE_CONTAINER| sed 's/^[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' )
      do
        echo $container
        continue
      done
    done
```

This is the file for container json :
lama baba

This is the file for storage json :
abdelvt33cpgsa abdelvt44cpgsa

This is the output I am getting 
abdelvt33cpgsa
lama
baba
abdelvt44cpgsa
lama
baba

and the expected result should be
abdelvt33cpgsa
lama
abdelvt44cpgsa
baba

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output? The way your code looks, your output should be separated by newlines. What part of your output is from `$storage` and which is from `$container`?

Comment: Do you actually want to *join* each line from the files?

Comment: @They are newlines but repeated and I have updated the post with what the storage json looks like and container json after filtering using jq.

Comment: @Jens No, I am trying to get first line and the second first line and second line and second line from each at same time without repeating them selfs.

Comment: So if the first file contains one letter per line, say, A, B, C; and the second file one number per line, like 1, 2, 3, what you want is 6 lines, A, 1, B, 2, C, 3?

Comment: @Jens Yes , thats exactly the sequence I need to output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right solution to this was to run it over aray loop.

```sh
    Potato=$(cat $TMP_FILE_STORAGE)
    Potato1=$(cat $TMP_FILE_CONTAINER)
    eval "array=($Potato)"
    eval "array2=($Potato1)"
    for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
    end=`date -d "15 minutes" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ'`
    az storage container generate-sas -n ${array2[$i]} --account-name ${array[$i]} --https-only --permissions dlrw --expiry $end -otsv`

      echo "First parameter : ${array[$i]} -- second parameter : ${array2[$i]}"

    done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- your files don't contain tab characters, and
- they have the same number of lines,

a quick way is to *paste* both files and then convert the separator character (tab by default) to newlines:

```
$ cat A-file
A
B
C
D D
E E
$ cat 1-file
1
2
3
4 4
5 5
$ paste A-file 1-file|tr '\t' '\n'
A
1
B
2
C
3
D D
4 4
E E
5 5
```

Look how Stackoverflow syntax coloring makes this example look cool!

Answer (score 0):

See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001); you shouldn't be using `for` loops in the first place.

Instead, use a `while` loop with two separate file descriptors.

```
while IFS= read -r storage <&3 && IFS= read -r container <&4 ; do
    echo "$storage"
    echo "$container"
done 3< <(sed 's/^[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' < "$TMP_FILE_STORAGE" ) 4< <(sed 's/^[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' < "$TMP_FILE_CONTAINER")
```

It appears you might be able to get rid of `sed` as well by splitting each input line on `"`:

```
while IFS=\" read -r _ storage _ <&3 &&
      IFS=\" read -r _ container _ <&4; do
    echo "$storage"
    echo "$container"
done 3< "$TMP_FILE_STORAGE" 4< "$TMP_FILE_CONTAINER"
```

Comment: The second version works but prints only once abdelvt33cpgsa
lama and skips abdelvt44cpgsa
baba

Comment: Probably because one of your input files doesn't end with a newline, as a POSIX text file (which `bash` assumes) is required to do.

Comment: but they are all on one line "a" "b" file number two "c" "d"

Comment: Oh, I thought they were one per line. Then you don't even need a loop.